# Prevent text field from blurring on button click

Tags: javascript, css, html

Let's say I have a field and a button. The button submits the field and triggers some AJAX request which returns data to the same page. Every time the button is clicked, the field is deselected/blurred. This can be partially fixed by making the button focus the text field upon its click. However, during the click, there is a brief moment where the field blurs. The way I have my page set up this does not look good. I would like to completely prevent the field from blurring throughout the click. What is the easiest way to do this? Thanks!

Code:

```
<input type="text" id="f" autofocus/><span id="btn" onclick="document.getElementById('f').focus()"></span>
```

Comment: Showing us some of your code would be a good first step.

Comment: Ok, I added what I think is the relevant code.

Comment: Are you looking to have this function the same in all browsers? Blur and focus can often be different in various browsers.

Comment: As long as it works in modern browsers I'm fine with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of handling button click you can move the focus on button focus with a very small timeout:

jQuery:

```
$('#btn').focus(function (event) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#f').focus();
    }, 5);
});
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('btn').onfocus = function (event) {
    setTimeout(function (event) {
        document.getElementById('f').focus();
    }, 5);
};
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked, except I changed `btn.onfocus` to `btn.onmousedown` to get it working. And I assume there's no way to do this in just CSS?